# what can i do with semantic web and xml and web services?

Tags: xml, web-services, semantic-web

i am a cs student and i need a project for fourth year using  : semantic web and xml and web services
so what the best (and new) project idea i can find from these technique

Answer (score 1):

For Web Services in general: find a data provider that exposes something via a web service and write an application that uses the data (e.g., http://msrmaps.com/webservices.aspx).

For Semantic Web: It's a pipe dream that revolves around the idea that if you have a simple syntax and a small vocabulary, you can unambiguously describe the world in both human- and machine-readable way. There are many variations on the basic promise: it can help programs find information in human-language documents, it can prevent misunderstandings between programs whose authors use different terminologies, it can help formalize existing business processes, etc. To choose a project that gets a high mark, it may help to find out what problem your professor thinks SW can solve.